# FANN Error 20: The number of output neurons in the ann (4196752) and data (1) don't match Epochs

Tags: c, ruby, neural-network, fann

This is a litle modified sample program I took from FANN website.

The equation I created is c = pow(a,2) + b.

**Train.c**

```
#include "fann.h"

int main()
{
    const unsigned int num_input = 2;
    const unsigned int num_output = 1;
    const unsigned int num_layers = 4;
    const unsigned int num_neurons_hidden = 3;
    const float desired_error = (const float) 0.001;
    const unsigned int max_epochs = 500000;
    const unsigned int epochs_between_reports = 1000;

    struct fann *ann = fann_create_standard(num_layers, num_input,
        num_neurons_hidden, num_output);

    fann_set_activation_function_hidden(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);
    fann_set_activation_function_output(ann, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC);

    fann_train_on_file(ann, "sample.data", max_epochs,
        epochs_between_reports, desired_error);

    fann_save(ann, "sample.net");

    fann_destroy(ann);

    return 0;
}
```

**Result.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "floatfann.h"

int main()
{
    fann_type *calc_out;
    fann_type input[2];

    struct fann *ann = fann_create_from_file("sample.net");

    input[0] = 1;
    input[1] = 1;
    calc_out = fann_run(ann, input);

    printf("sample test (%f,%f) -> %f\n", input[0], input[1], calc_out[0]);

    fann_destroy(ann);
    return 0;
}
```

I created my own dataset

dataset.rb

```
f= File.open("sample.data","w")

f.write("100 2 1\n")

i=0
while i<100 do 
    first = rand(0..100)
    second = rand(0..100)
    third = first ** 2 + second
    string1 = "#{first} #{second}\n"
    string2 = "#{third}\n"
    f.write(string1)
    f.write(string2)
    i=i+1
end

f.close
```

**sample.data**

```
100 2 1
95  27
9052
63  9 
3978
38  53
1497
31  84
1045
28  56
840
95  80
9105
10  19
...
...
```

sample data first line gives number of samples, number of inputs and last number of outputs.

But I am getting an error 
`FANN Error 20: The number of output neurons in the ann (4196752) and data (1) don't match Epochs`

What's the issue here? How does it calculate `4196752` neurons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, using [fann_create_standard](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann-h.html#fann_create_standard), the function signature is `fann_create_standard(num_layers, layer1_size, layer2_size, layer3_size...)`, whilst you are trying to use it differently:

```
struct fann *ann = fann_create_standard(num_layers, num_input,
        num_neurons_hidden, num_output);
```

you construct a network with 4 layers, but only provide data for 3. The 4196752 neurons in the output layer are likely coming from an undefined value.

Comment: But I have clearly defined number of inputs 2 and output 1, just that the hidden layers contains 3 neurons, how does it affect?

Comment: @InQusitive: Read the documentation, the params are `(num_of_layers,...)` where each param after the first is the size of a layer. You have asked for 4 layer network, and only provided data for 3. Just because you call the variable `num_output` does not make it the last layer required by the constructor.